# A linear invertible plane transformation preserve lines.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

I need verification in my attempt of proof.

Let $B:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ a linear invertible transformation.

Since it's linear, then $B(0)=B(x-x)=B(x)-B(x)=0$.

Let $p \in l$ some line, then $ax_p +by_p +c=0$. Then $aB(x_p)+bB(y_p)+cB(1)=0$, then $B(p)$ is in a line of equation $ax+by+cB(1)=0$, then $B$ does preserve lines.

I'm not sure if I did it right, specially because I can't see where invertible property was used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $B$ "eats" vectors (elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$) while $x_p,y_p$ are real numbers (the coordinates of the point $(x_p,y_p)$ that lies on the line $l$ whose equation is given by $ax + by + c = 0$) and so you can't apply $B$ to $x_p,y_p$!

Instead of describing lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a solution to a non-homogeneous linear equations, it is better to describe them using a single parameter and vectors and then you can apply $B$ to the points on the line and see what you get.

Namely, a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be described by

$$ l = \{ p_0 + t \cdot v \, | \, t \in \mathbb{R} \} $$

where $p_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is some point on the line $l$ and $0 \neq v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is the direction vector of the line. Then

$$ B(l) = \{ B(p_0 + t \cdot v) \, | \, t \in \mathbb{R} \} = \{ B(p_0) + t B(v) \, | \, t \in \mathbb{R} \} $$

and since $B$ is invertible, $B(v)$ is non-zero and so $B(l)$ is a line that passes through the point $B(p_0)$ with direction $B(v)$.

Comment: Is this correct?  $B(v) \neq 0$ follow from invertible property:  The inverse of a linear is linear and then $B(x)=0 \Rightarrow x=B^{-1}(0)=0$

Comment: You don't need to use the fact that $B^{-1}$ is linear. Since $B$ is invertible, $B$ is one-to-one and so $B(x) = B(0) = 0$ implies that $x = 0$.